# How is Django makemigrations triggered for changes to a custom model field?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a custom model field defined as:

```
class PriceField(models.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_digits'] = 30
        kwargs['decimal_places'] = 20
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want to change it so that it is also nullable/blankable so I add:

```
class PriceField(models.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_digits'] = 30
        kwargs['decimal_places'] = 20
        kwargs['null'] = True
        kwargs['blank'] = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, having made this addition and running `makemigrations`, no new migrations are created. Having read the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction I thought that the problem might be the lack of a `deconstruct()` method, but even after adding one as seems to be described in the docs (which I read as being to delete the kwargs you override in the init method):

```
    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        del kwargs['max_digits']
        del kwargs['decimal_places']
        del kwargs['null']
        del kwargs['blank']
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

...it still doesn't create any migrations to make the field nullable/blankable. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass null and blank arguments to your field initialization inside the model definition like in any other standard django field

Comment: That creates the migrations (if I remove the defaults from the custom field) and will be my backup plan, but I was hoping I could keep the supposed advantages of having defined a custom class i.e. that I only need to set the default arguments in one place rather than everywhere this field is used.